# React TypeScript HoC composition results in incompatible JSX element type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm trying to use `react-redux-firebase` with TypeScript but whenever I try to connect a component using `firebaseConnect`, the compiler tells me that the resulting component does not have any construct or call signatures.

For example

```
export default compose(
  firebaseConnect(),
  connect(({ firebase: { auth } }) => ({ auth }))
)(Login);
```

When the resulting HoC is used in JSX, TS tells me:

> JSX element type 'Login' does not have any construct or call
>   signatures.

If I leave out the `firebaseConnect()` from compose everything is fine.

The type definition of the function is `export function firestoreConnect(...args: any[]): any;`
.

How can I possibly work around this? I'm using React 16 with `"@types/react": "^16.0.18",`